# Difficulty adding a new view to a Roo-generated project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, view, spring-roo

I'm trying to add my custom view and controller to a VERY basic roo-generated project.

By using Spring Tool Suite (STS, Spring 3.1) I created a new project and then ran the following 3 commands:

```
    persistence setup --database MYSQL --provider HIBERNATE --userName *** --password *** --databaseName ***
    entity jpa --class com.demoing.domain.Customer --testAutomatically 
    field string --fieldName firstName --notNull 
    field string --fieldName lastName --notNull 
    controller scaffold --class com.demoing.controller.CustomerController --entity com.demoing.domain.Customer
```

After generating these, the application can be started on the server.

However, when I add a new .jspx file (Like home.jspx) the application says "Resource not found" when going to the specific link. I added to jspx next to other views in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jspx

I've added the view's definition in views.xml and manually created a controller as seen below:

```
package com.demoing.domain;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@Scope(value = "session")
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(produces="text/html")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request, Model uiModel ){

        return "home";
    }
}
```

And the views definition:

```
  <definition name="home" extends="public">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jspx" />
  </definition>
```

All I want is to display a completely new, empty page. However when I go to "project/home" it says "resource not found".

I really don't understand what I'm missing and I hope someone with a bit more experience with these things can help me out.

Comment: Your Tiles and JSP stuff looks, ok. Which URL do you request?

Comment: I'm requesting http://localhost:8080/Rest_Demo/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following question and answer on StackOverflow

[Adding a custom page in spring roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687282/adding-a-custom-page-in-spring-roo)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea: Put your `HomeController` controller in the package `com.demoing.controller`, where the other controllers are.

*I do not know exactly, but maybe Roo configured Spring to scan only this package (and subpackages) for controllers.*

Comment: Double check for typos and check that everything is correct deployed

Comment: Of course did that. Have been working on a half-done project so far and haven't encountered these starting problems.

Comment: Can you upload the project anywhere so that I can have a look?